# Dataframe set_index produces duplicate index values instead of doing hierarchical grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this (index not shown)

```
Time   Letter   Type    Value
    0    A       x       10
    0    B       y       20
    1    A       y       30
    1    B       x       40
    3    C       x       50
```

I want to produce a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Time    Letter   TypeX    TypeY
  0        A      10       20
  0        B               20
  1        A               30
  1        B      40       
  3        C      50
```

To do that, I decided I would first create a table that have multiple indices, Time, Letter and then unstack the last index Type.

Let's say my original dataframe was named my_table:

my_table.reset_index().set_index(['Time', 'Letter']) and instead of grouping it so that under every time index, letter there is BOTH Type X and Type Y, they seemed to have been sorted (adding a few more entries to demonstrate a point):

```
Time(i) Letter(i)   Type    Value
    0    A       x       10
         D       x       25
         H       x       15
         G       x       33
    1    B       x       40
         G       x       10
    3    C       x       50
    0    B       y       20
         H       y       10
    1    A       y       30
```

Why does this happen? I expected a result like so:

```
Time   Letter   Type    Value
    0    A       x       10
                 y       30
         B       y       20
         H       x       15
                 y       10
         D       x       25
         G       x       33
    1    B       x       40
         G       x       10
    3    C       x       50
```

The same behavior occurs when I make Type one of the indices, it just becomes bold as an index.

How do I successfully group columns using Time and Letter to get X and Y to be matched by those columns, so I can successfully use unstack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set type as the index as well

```
df.set_index(['Time','Letter','Type']).Value.unstack(fill_value='').reset_index()
Out[178]: 
Type  Time Letter   x   y
0        0      A  10    
1        0      B      20
2        1      A      30
3        1      B  40    
4        3      C  50
```